# Is it neccessary to close mongodb connection after manipulating or fetching data?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have this below code it works correctly but should I close the connection after returning the data? If yes so how to close the connection?

```
// project.db.js

 const { MongoClient, ObjectId } = require("mongodb");
 const { mongo_uri, dbName } = require("../config/constants");

// connect method
 function connection() {
    return MongoClient.connect(mongo_uri);
 }
// async function which read data
  exports.allProject_tasks = async (space_id) => {
        try {
        const result = await connection();
        const db = await result.db(dbName);
        const payload = await db
       .collection("tasks")
         .find({
            user_space_id: ObjectId(space_id),
          })
     .toArray();
     return payload;
 } catch {
    return 400;
}
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always best to close the connection when the job is done from app side to release the allocated connection resources on database server side( mongoDB allocated ~1MB per connection meaning that if you open 1000 connections your server will allocate ~1GB only for connections) , and if you leave the resource to be released by the connection timeouts this could lead to issues when server is under high load if the timeout is higher.

Comment: @RD2D thanks for your answer but in my case should I write a separate function to close the connection?

Comment: @PaimanRasoli : In high load multithreading applications the connections are open in connection pool and later reused by all functions interacting with the database and closed only when there is no need of them , so this is up to you to decide if you will do in separate function  depending on how your application works.